# Make Tensorflow only consider consecutive rows of data

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have data which consists of a timestamp and some other data fields. However, some of my entries are not to be considered for learning, and I thus have removed them from the data. I ended up with a dataset like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
7
8
9
10
```

(note the gap at 6). Now, for learning, I want Tensorflow to consider the last 3 rows (and get the prediction label from the following row), but with taking the gaps into consideration. In my example, the valid data packages would be (1,2,3,4), (2,3,4,5), and (7,8,9,10), but not e.g. (3,4,5,7).

I've looked into the Tensorflow API, and it seems that an own implementation of [Datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) might do the trick, although at first sight, the class doesn't look like a natural candidate for such an approach (e.g., no abstract super class where only some tiny `next()` method has to be implemented ;-)).

Any other ideas? How would you approach that problem?

Comment: `However, some of my entries are not to be considered for learning, and I thus have removed them from the data`: Do you still have them, or are they definitely gone?

Comment: I still have them (and can easily see by the data which they are)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most straightforward way is to use the windowing capabilities of the `tf.data.Dataset` API, and to filter for values that are relevant.

For example, if reuse your example:

```
# creating a dataset of the values 1 to 10
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(1,11)
# elements that we don't want in the dataset
to_remove = tf.constant([6])
# creating windows of size 4 with a shfit of 1. We keep only windows of size 4
windows = ds.window(size=4, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
# window returns a Dataset of Dataset, we flatten it to get a Dataset of Tensor
windows = windows.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(4, drop_remainder=True))
# we filter to keep only the correct elements
filtered = windows.filter(lambda x: not tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(x,to_remove[:,tf.newaxis])))
```

If we look at the final dataset:

```
>>> for data in filtered:
        print(data)
tf.Tensor([1 2 3 4], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2 3 4 5], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([ 7  8  9 10], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Your answer probably has all I need, although I have some difficulties applying it to my concrete setting... I find it rather difficult to debug Tensorflow code.

Comment: The filtering part might be the most difficult part. Don't hesitate to ask another question, more specific, if needed.